# versioning or using different gems for next API verion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, versioning, gemfile

I have written some Rails `API` little long ago. I used `namespace`,`module` for making different versions of it.

Now I need to move my `API`s to next version. Where I need to use different `gem`s to achieve the requirement(need to add and delete some extra `gem`s). While keeping the present version running for some more time.

I can use `namespace`, `module`s for routes and business logic changes. But how can I specify different `gem`s for this version of `API`?

Does creating a separate `git branch` is the solution?
or
should I use different `Gemfile`.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In same application if you want to add a new Gemfile, then I think it will be better option to create a engine and keep it inside `vendors` folder, so it will be inside your application and you will get separate routes, namespaces and Gemfile for that.
You can check the link given below about engine development.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html